# Fully random PN sequence

Tags: digital-communications, radio

Can a CDMA PN sequence be fully random, as in encryption-grade randomness, or must it be deterministic? I have tried the first bytes of SHA-256 hashes as PN sequences, but somehow they don't coexist too well.

I know a deterministic code can be generated on-the-fly so no storage is needed, but let's say I have 500 fully random PN sequences stored on a device. Is that good or do you really need deterministic codes like the Gold codes?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE. To really take advantage of CDMA, [you need to have **guaranteed** very low correlation](http://www.wirelesscommunication.nl/reference/chaptr05/cdma/codes/codes.htm). Simply generating random codes does not cut it, regardless of whether the noise generator is "encryption-grade" or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical type of "pseudo-random" sequences used in CDMA is the "m-sequences" that also provide good properties in wireless channels with multipath. Have a look to this post for more information about these: http://www.behindthesciences.com/towards-5g/directsequencespreadspectrumandrakereceiver

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. It's not so much about being random as it is about using codes that do not interfere with each other. Even a fully random code could have a chance at corrupting another fully random code.

Comment: that's it! happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean under *encryption-grade randomness*?

It is *not* recommended to use *linear* random generator in most of the encryption cases.

PN-Sequence is a mutation of the [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register). Because of the linearity, all future values [can be calculated easily](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/cracking-a-linear-congruential-generator). So be careful using linear pseudo random generators.